# Training with different datasets for the same better VAE model yields poor results

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorflow, generative-models, vae

The VAE model I used here https://github.com/keras-team/keras-io/blob/master/examples/generative/vae.py.
It can produce very well results for the minist and fashion minist dataset.

But when I use my datasets, the results are pretty terrible. So I sincerely hope you can help me to provide me some guidance.

**The problems** are as followings:

1. My datasets are composed of many circles in the image, as shown:

[image]

The shape of the datasets is `[238, 28, 28, 1]`, and the range of pixel value is between `0` and `1` `(floats32)`.

2. But the result is terrible.
   **The loss value**
   [image]
   **The genetive images:**
   [image]